# Weighted average where one weight is infinite

Tags: python, numpy

Using NumPy's weighted average, I expected an element with infinite weighting to dominate the result, but instead it returns `NaN`,

```
>>> np.average([1,2], weights=[np.inf, 1])
nan
```

Was this an intentional design?  It seems counter-intuitive.

---

EDIT: here's a more simple example:

```
>>> np.average([1], weights=[np.inf])
nan
```

Comment: `(1*inf + 2*1) / (inf+1)` == `inf / inf`. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Though not intentional, it is mathematically correct.

You end up with a formula like infinity/infinity. The result depends on which infinitiy is larger. And that is nonsense.

You need concrete numbers as weights, so you could use very large ones.

Comment: I think that the mathematical correctness **is** intentional, especially in numpy. :) And the result of `inf/inf` does not depend on anything. It's simply undefined.

Comment: If only one weight is infinite, say the first element as in my example above, then the weighted average (w_0*x_0 + w_1*x_1)/(w_0 + w_1) becomes, in the limit of w_0 going to infinity, (w_0*x_0)/w_0 = x_0.   However, if two or more weights are infinite, then I agree with your logic.

Comment: @Garrett Yes, which is a different problem with different solution. And BTW: you've just discovered that operating on the infinity symbol is not the same as operating on limits. Which is mathematically correct. After all `x/x -> 1` even though `inf/inf` is still undefined.

Comment: No. Numpy will only use the given formula, which ends in inf/inf. You add some additional logic like "if there are inf weights, then"). Your calculation is mathematically wrong, if w0=inf. You may think this calculation is possible, but then you will geht into trouble in other cases. For example, what do you expect if one point is x0=0; w0=inf and a second x1=inf; w1=1?

Comment: @sweber, in the example you give, you end up have (Indeterminate + x1)/(w0 + 1), where x1 and w0 are infinite but possibly unequal.  That's certainly different than (w1 * x1) / w1.

Comment: Intersting, I see R (`weighted.mean(c(1,2), c(Inf,1)) == NaN`) and Mathematica (`Mean[WeightedData[{1, 2}, {Infinity, 2}]] == Indeterminate`) both agree with you.  Hmmm....

Comment: @Garret: To make it more clear: If you have two unimaginable large numbers, which are equal, then the division of both is 1. However, "infinite" is not something that defines a certain number. It is more something like "the end of all numbers". Within a formula, a computer does not say "Hey, these are infinite, but equal numbers, so we can cancle them". Even in math, one does not handle with infinity itself, but a series of numbers increasing to infinity (limes)

Comment: @Garret: One more comment: "the end of all numbers" sounds strange for a human, but not for a computer and its limited number ranges. Usually, a computer would (should) throw an exception when it tries to calculate something it can not calculate. Therefore, +/-inf is used to denote that the value is out of range. There is also +/-nan for not allowed calculations like 1/0 or log(-5). But these are no numbers. But some further calculations may be possible, for example 1.0/numpy.inf is 0.0.